# gcc preprocessor: can I resolve #if[def]s only, leave other directives untouched?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I'm doing some reverse engineering on some old code that is configured by a massive tangle of #ifs and #ifdefs.  I'm currently looking at the various configurations by doing the substitutions in an editor.  This is both tedious and (I suspect) error-prone.

Are there some gcc preprocessor options that will preprocess the #if[def]s but leave other preprocessor directives (e.g. #define) untouched?  This is for reverse engineering purposes only; I don't need to compile or otherwise use the preprocessed code.

Comment: you could comment defines with sed/perl

Comment: @Anycorn: Yes, perhaps keep them _and_ add a comment with the contents of the `#define`.

Comment: Is the output of `gcc -E` otherwise useful to you, or is this too much preprocessing?

Comment: There might be some useful tips [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7409003/745924).

Comment: There's definitely a tool for this, but I forget its name...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any such functionality in gcc's preprocessor.  And depending on what you're trying to do, it might not even be possible.  If a `#ifdef` directive refers to a macro previously defined (or not) by a `#define` directive, and you ignore `#define` directives, then that's clearly not going to work.

But the [unifdef](http://freecode.com/projects/unifdef) command is likely to be what you're looking for.  I just installed it on my Ubuntu system with `sudo apt-get install unifdef`; there should be similar ways to install it on other systems.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to compile it, you can use the IDE's ability to understand ifdefs. In Eclipse, head to *Project > Preferences > C/C++ Build > Paths and Symbols*, and define the symbols you want. Eclipse will then ignore any ifdef whose symbols was not defined.

Comment: I'm working at the command line now, but this sounds like a great suggestion that I'll keep in mind for future use.  Thanks!